# Calculating difference between the most recent 2 days with criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

I am trying to calculate the difference/change with respect to the previous week. I am trying to emphasize the trend overtime(like running balance). I have used this formula in excel however could not complete the last piece. Using sumifs below is optional.

```
=SUMIFS([SalesUnit],[Date],[@[Date]],[Location],[@Location])-SUMIFS([SalesUnit],[Location],[@Location],[Date],[@[Date]]))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have Xlookup you can do a reverse search for the next lowest date like this:

```
=[@SalesUnit]-XLOOKUP(1,([Location]=[@Location])*([Date]<[@Date]),[SalesUnit],,0,-1)
```

[image]

I have left the #N/A in but you could wrap the formula in Iferror to hide it:

```
=IFERROR([@SalesUnit]-XLOOKUP(1,([Location]=[@Location])*([Date]<[@Date]),[SalesUnit],,0,-1),"")
```